# How to change python2 to python3

Tags: python-3.x

I need to change python2 to python3 (OS X El Capitan).

I downloaded python3 via Homebrew and installed it successfully, but when I am trying to reach it via

```
$ python3
```

python3 throws:

```
python3: posix_spawn: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.62.7: No such file or directory
```

and if I ask:

```
$ python --version
```

I see:

```
Python 2.7.10
```

(my previous version).

What should I do to be able to continue my work with python3?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your $python --version, remember that python runs python 2.x, and it is $python3--version that will give you the version of python3, which is the command that runs python 3.x (or it tell you that python3 doesn't exist)

Assuming you still have issues, I am not familiar with Homebrew, but have some general tips for this situation (I am assuming this is Unix):

Use whereis python3 to find its path, or it may not print anything at all, which shows you don't have it. Hunt around with terminal or some other application and investigate where python is found (cd /, then sudo find -name python)

Use something like apt in terminal if Homebrew is creating issues

Try again: Delete the files (or use apt purge python3) and try again. Make sure to use the correct out of 32 or 64 bit version, with the newest python 3 version

Comment: Thank you so much, after your comment I revised my question. The essence of my question has changed.